# What is the negative form of "as well as"?

Tags: grammar

I want to form such a sentence:
You can not do this as well as you should not do that...
should I use "just as"?

is there a better and more elegant use like the one if there is any with neither?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should not play with fire *any more than* you should play with strong acid.**

Your suggestion to use "just as"  would also work.

You should not invest all your money in a pyramid scheme *just as* you should not gamble it all on a horse race.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot do this, that, that, and that.

Or

> You cannot do this, and that, too.

*as well as* doesn't go well, or at all, with negative sentences.

*neither/nor* combination is generally accepted.

> You can neither do this, nor that.

**Note:** You cannot say this at all:

> You cannot neither do this, nor that.